# Kubernetes - unable to setup DNS

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

After installing kubernetes according to: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html I am unable to setup dns addon.

Kubelet is running:

```
● kubelet.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-07-11 08:30:18 UTC; 35min ago
  Process: 5489 ExecStop=/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5507 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5503 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/containers (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5501 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5519 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 21 (limit: 32768)
   Memory: 67.1M
      CPU: 40.541s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           ├─5519 /kubelet --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --register-schedulable=false --cni-conf-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d --network-plugin= --container-runtime=docker --allow-privileged=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/
           └─5574 journalctl -k -f
```

But kube-dns is unable to connect to api-server:

```
I0711 09:04:36.117052       1 dns.go:42] version: v1.6.0-alpha.0.680+3872cb93abf948-dirty
I0711 09:04:36.117449       1 server.go:107] Using https://10.3.0.1:443 for kubernetes master, kubernetes API: <nil>
I0711 09:04:36.118188       1 server.go:63] ConfigMap not configured, using values from command line flags
I0711 09:04:36.118223       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I0711 09:04:36.118234       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map=""
I0711 09:04:36.118241       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
I0711 09:04:36.118246       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
I0711 09:04:36.118264       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I0711 09:04:36.118271       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I0711 09:04:36.118277       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --federations=""
I0711 09:04:36.118289       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I0711 09:04:36.118294       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
I0711 09:04:36.118299       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
I0711 09:04:36.118303       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I0711 09:04:36.118310       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I0711 09:04:36.118315       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I0711 09:04:36.118322       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I0711 09:04:36.118327       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I0711 09:04:36.118331       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --v="0"
I0711 09:04:36.118335       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --version="false"
I0711 09:04:36.118342       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I0711 09:04:36.119467       1 server.go:155] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
I0711 09:04:36.119543       1 server.go:167] Skydns metrics not enabled
I0711 09:04:36.119626       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0711 09:04:36.119644       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
E0711 09:05:06.120481       1 reflector.go:199] pkg/dns/dns.go:145: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0711 09:05:06.120729       1 reflector.go:199] pkg/dns/dns.go:148: Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Logs from api server:

```
[restful] 2017/07/11 07:52:32 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://10.10.0.201:443/swaggerapi/
[restful] 2017/07/11 07:52:32 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] https://10.10.0.201:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
I0711 07:52:32.740429       1 serve.go:79] Serving securely on 0.0.0.0:443
I0711 07:52:32.740816       1 serve.go:94] Serving insecurely on 127.0.0.1:8080
I0711 07:52:33.679354       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication" (started 2017-07-11 07:52:32.965645672 +0000 UTC):
[28.85µs] [28.85µs] About to convert to expected version
[104.67µs] [75.82µs] Conversion done
[111.099µs] [6.429µs] About to store object in database
[713.576512ms] [713.465413ms] Object stored in database
[713.584455ms] [7.943µs] Self-link added
"Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication" [713.659549ms] [75.094µs] END
I0711 08:08:32.606430       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager" (started 2017-07-11 08:08:31.933189525 +0000 UTC):
[8.907µs] [8.907µs] About to convert to expected version
[19.758µs] [10.851µs] Conversion done
[23.027µs] [3.269µs] About to store object in database
[673.145516ms] [673.122489ms] Object stored in database
[673.153091ms] [7.575µs] Self-link added
"Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager" [673.202028ms] [48.937µs] END
I0711 08:20:10.566203       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler" (started 2017-07-11 08:20:07.032156665 +0000 UTC):
[22.756µs] [22.756µs] About to convert to expected version
[40.481µs] [17.725µs] Conversion done
[44.63µs] [4.149µs] About to store object in database
[3.533855608s] [3.533810978s] Object stored in database
[3.53385947s] [3.862µs] Self-link added
"Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler" [3.53395749s] [98.02µs] END
I0711 08:20:10.568558       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager" (started 2017-07-11 08:20:08.786760574 +0000 UTC):
[12.63µs] [12.63µs] About to convert to expected version
[29.044µs] [16.414µs] Conversion done
[32.943µs] [3.899µs] About to store object in database
[1.781715989s] [1.781683046s] Object stored in database
[1.78171996s] [3.971µs] Self-link added
"Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager" [1.781762523s] [42.563µs] END
I0711 08:20:48.669858       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler" (started 2017-07-11 08:20:45.030964285 +0000 UTC):
[11.455µs] [11.455µs] About to convert to expected version
[25.762µs] [14.307µs] Conversion done
[29.427µs] [3.665µs] About to store object in database
[3.638826479s] [3.638797052s] Object stored in database
[3.638829618s] [3.139µs] Self-link added
"Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler" [3.638855999s] [26.381µs] END
I0711 08:20:48.670137       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Update /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager" (started 2017-07-11 08:20:45.495019689 +0000 UTC):
[13.604µs] [13.604µs] About to convert to expected version
[33.752µs] [20.148µs] Conversion done
[37.844µs] [4.092µs] About to store object in database
[3.175049169s] [3.175011325s] Object stored in database
```

Api server ips:

```
# ip addr                                                                                                 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:a7:f2:78:8d:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.201/24 brd 10.10.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5ca7:f2ff:fe78:8d04/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether ae:1e:17:85:1b:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.13.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ac1e:17ff:fe85:1b63/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:06:e4:42:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

DNS Service:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get svc -o wide
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE       SELECTOR
kube-dns               10.3.0.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   1h        k8s-app=kube-dns
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the API server address (10.10.0.201) and the API server address the DNS service is trying to access (10.3.0.1) do not match. The DNS service must be configured to use 10.10.0.201 as the API address.

I think the `--api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080` in Kubelet (I assume that the kube-dns service may be running in a different node from the api server) may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: According to link I posted above this is single master configuration and api server is listening insecurely on localhost and securely on all addresses. `  - name: kube-apiserver
...    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - apiserver
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - --etcd-servers=http://10.10.0.201:2379
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/24
    - --secure-port=443
    - --advertise-address=10.10.0.201
...
    - --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true
    - --anonymous-auth=false
    - --storage-backend=etcd2

Comment: I tired but it makes no difference